# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpss_social_addtoany_js'

Tags: plugins

I have made an update of the plugins and themes and now it throws me this warning.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpss_social_addtoany_js' not found or invalid function name in /home/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you’ve updated the plugins and themes and the error shows up.

This error means that you try to use function that no longer is defined.

Most probably it was defined in a plugin and the newer version changed its API. And your theme (or some other plugin) is still using the old API.

**So how to fix that?**

- Download your code.
- Search for occurrence of that function call and
  locate all of them.
- If they’re located in your own code, modify it to
  use current API.
- If they’re in third party code - notify their
  authors and wait for fixes or stop using them.